# Assign object values to class values

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I've encountered a problem with assigning object values to class values. Basically, let's say that I have a class Account and an object with the same properties as the class

```js
class Account {
    id: Number;
    name: String;
}

const accountObject = {
    id: 4216,
    name: "Test name"

}
const account = new Account();
//set values from accountObject to account as a class
account.id = accountObject.id;
//...
```

So is there a way to assign values from an object to a class without doing it manually? I have a lot of properties that I need to be assigned and doing it by hand would solve the issue but if there's a prettier way to do so, I'd really appreciate any help

Comment: `for(let k in accountObject){ account[k] = accountObject[k]; }`

Comment: I believe you could also use http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Object/extend/

`cost account = new Account(); Object.extend(account, accountObject);`

Comment: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) might help `const account = Object.assign(accountObject, new Account())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop should do the trick:

```js
class Foo {
    name = "foo"
    age = 1
}

const foo = new Foo()

const bar = {
    name: "bar",
    age: 100
}

for (let key in bar) {
    foo[key] = bar[key]
}

console.log(foo) // prints Foo { name: 'bar', age: 100 }

console.log('----------------------------------');

Object.entries(bar).forEach(
    ([key, value]) => (foo[key] = value)
)

console.log(foo) // prints Foo { name: 'bar', age: 100 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Account {
  constructor({
    id,
    name
  }) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

const account = new Account({
  id: 4216,
  name: "Test name"
});

console.log(account);
```